# URL Rewrite and IIS configuration

Tags: asp.net, url-routing

My environment is VS2010 and windows 7. i am doing url rewrite with routing for extension less rewrite. everything works fine but i did not configure my IIS and also did not write nothing in my web.config file for url rewrite. everything is working fine.

so i want to know that when i host my project to orcsweb then they need to configure IIS or do i need to write anything in web.config or should i need to tell them that i am using routing so they should use IIS7 instead of IIS6.

my sample code for url rewrite like

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Source", "Source/{ID}/{Title}", "~/Source.aspx");
        RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Source1", "MyData/Source/{ID}/{Title}", "~/MyData/Source.aspx");
    }
```

please discuss in detail.......thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is nice if they upgrade to IIS7 anyway, since it has much better support for .NET

Anyway, if .NET framework 3.5 SP1 (or highier) is installed and configured on machine, Routing should simply work. No additional configuration is needed.